# next working day in php

Tags: php, yii

I want to get last working day, I have count of total numbers of days from start date.
my code is below

```
function get_working_date($date,$days) {
      $add_day = $days;
      $new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date +$add_day Days"));
      $leaves = $this->getOfficialLeaves($date,$new_date);
      $weekendDays =$this->countWeekendDays($date,$new_date,false);
      $totleave =$weekendDays + $leaves;
      if(count($add_day)>0){
        $add_day = $totleave+ $add_day;
        echo $add_day; die;
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date +$add_day Days"));
       return $new_date;
      }
      return $new_date;
  }
```

In this code I have count to total numbers of leave in that period.But not getting solution for get exact end working date. Please help me out

Comment: Can we help with a specific question or do you want someone to just correct the code for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-08-26 +1 Weekday'));
?>
```

This should do it.